# Rust in two different projects but same Cargo.toml. The other project is giving me an issue of dependency issue

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Rust in two different projects but same Cargo.toml. The other project is giving me an issue of dependency issue while the other one is building fine. Both are compiling and in the same rust nightly build.

Am I missing anything?

Below is the error that I am seeing when I do `cargo build

```
error: failed to select a version for the requirement `pbkdf2 = "^0.2.0"`
candidate versions found which didn't match: 0.9.0, 0.8.0, 0.7.5, ...
required by package `mongodb v0.3.12`
    ... which satisfies dependency `mongodb = "^0.3.12"` of package `r2d2-mongodb v0.2.2`
    ... which satisfies dependency `r2d2-mongodb = "^0.2.2"` of package
```

Here's my cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
anyhow = "1.0.34"
chrono = { version = "0.4.19", features = ["serde"] }
dotenv = "0.15.0"
jsonwebtoken = "7.2.0"
r2d2 = "0.8.9"
r2d2-mongodb = "0.2.2"
rand = "0.7.3"
rocket = "0.4.8"
rocket_contrib = { version = "0.4.8", features = ["helmet", "uuid"] }
rust-argon2 = "0.8.2"
serde = { version = "1.0.117", features = ["derive"] }
uuid = { version = "0.8.1", features = ["serde", "v4"] }
log = "0.4"
log4rs = "0.8"

[dev-dependencies]
lazy_static = "1.4.0"
serde_json = "1.0.59"
```

My rustc version

```
rustc 1.56.0-nightly (29ef6cf16 2021-08-31)
```

Comment: `r2d2-mongodb` is [deprecated](https://github.com/sfackler/r2d2) with the reason: *"official driver handles pooling internally"*. You should use the official `mongodb` crate directly instead.

Comment: I will take a look at the mongodb. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
failed to select a version for the requirement `pbkdf2 = "^0.2.0"`
```

A transitive dependency is looking for a `pbkdf2` 0.2.x dependency. However, all versions of [`pbkdf2`](https://crates.io/crates/pbkdf2) prior to 0.3.0 have been [yanked from crates.io](https://crates.io/crates/pbkdf2/versions). I haven't found a specific reason why, it could be due to a security vulnerability or other error on the authors' part, wherein they've decided these versions shouldn't be used.

The likely reason you get the error in one project and not the other is because one has a `Cargo.lock` file that has already selected a `pbkdf2` 0.2 version. [Yanking](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-yank.html) doesn't prevent a version's use, only prevents *new* crates from depending on it.

The fix is to copy the `Cargo.lock` from the working project to the other.

Comment: Thank you! I am a newbie on Rust, and I keep wondering and googling, but I am just going in circles.